# Bitmap image not being rendered correctly

Tags: java

I have this image

[image]

This is simply a circle which becomes more transparent towards the edge. If I blit this image to the screen, I see the following:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea why my image would be drawn to the screen like this? Here are my relevant functions:

```
public void blit(Bitmap bitmap, int x, int y) {
    int x0 = x;
    int x1 = x + bitmap.width;
    int y0 = y;
    int y1 = y + bitmap.height;
    if (x0 < 0)
        x0 = 0;
    if (y0 < 0)
        y0 = 0;
    if (x1 > width)
        x1 = width;
    if (y1 > height)
        y1 = height;
    int ww = x1 - x0;

    for (int yy = y0; yy < y1; yy++) {
        int tp = yy * width + x0;
        int sp = (yy - y) * bitmap.width + (x0 - x);
        tp -= sp;
        for (int xx = sp; xx < sp + ww; xx++) {
            int col = bitmap.pixels[xx];
            if (col < 0 && (tp+xx) < pixels.length){
                pixels[tp + xx] = normal(col, pixels[tp + xx]);
            }
        }
    }
}
    public static int normal(int a, int b) {
        int aA = (a >> 24) & 0xff;
        int aR = ((a & 0xff0000) >> 16);
        int aG = ((a & 0xff00) >> 8);
        int aB = (a & 0xff);

        int bA = (b >> 24) & 0xff;
        int bR = ((b & 0xff0000) >> 16);
        int bG = ((b & 0xff00) >> 8);
        int bB = (b & 0xff);

        float alpha = aA / 255f;

        if (aA == 255 || bA == 0){
            return a;
        }

        float srcAlpha = aA * (1 / 255f);
        float dstAlpha = bA * (1 / 255f);
        int A = (int) (aA+bA*(1-srcAlpha));
        int R = (int) (aR*srcAlpha+bR*dstAlpha*(1-srcAlpha));
        int G = (int) (aG*srcAlpha+bG*dstAlpha*(1-srcAlpha));
        int B = (int) (aB*srcAlpha+bB*dstAlpha*(1-srcAlpha));

        return A << 24 | R << 16 | G << 8 | B;
}
//code for importing image
public static Bitmap getBitmap(String location){
    try{
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(ImageHandler.class.getResource(location));

        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());

        for(int i = 0; i < image.getWidth(); i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < image.getHeight(); j++){
                int rgb = image.getRGB(i, j);
                if(rgb != 0xFFFF00FF && rgb != 0xFF990099){
                    bitmap.setPixel(rgb, i, j);
                }
            }
        }

        return bitmap;
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

I'm really sorry if this question seems vague, I'm just really lost with this one! thanks in advanced. I personally think that the answer lies somewhere within how I'm actually blitting the pixels and how they're being overlayed.

**UPDATE**

I've been playing around with the code and it's to do with a certain value not being calculate correctly, if i pass in

```
int colour = 0x80FF0000;
```

Then the program reads the alpha was 128, however, if i pass in:

```
int colour = 0x79FF0000;
```

The alpha is suddenly read as 254, therefore making the image get cut off.

```
float aA = (a >> 24) & 0x000000FF;
```

is how i extract the alpha

```
float srcAlpha = aA / 255F;
```

is how i extract the source alpha

**EDIT 2**

The problem is not with rounding, it's with buffering.

```
buffer.renderTest(); //buffer is of type Bitmap
```

will render a gradient on the screen perfectly

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(buffer.width, buffer.height);
b.renderTest();
buffer.blit(b, 0, 0);
```

however will cut  off once transparency becomes below 0x79000000
does that mean the issuses is with my blit function?

Comment: Why do you use `bA*(1-srcAlpha)+0.5?

Comment: @ShaunWild Since you couldn't upload the original transparent image yesterday I recreated it as you suggested (https://i.imgur.com/EIP794Y.png) and tested it using your exact blending function (https://i.imgur.com/THTvUW1.png). It works fine, so I can only suggest that your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @Boann What on earth could the problem be then? Could of possible be the way I'm loading the image into an RGBA Integer array? I edited my question to show the getBitmap code

Comment: @ShaunWild I can't see anything *obviously* wrong. Perhaps you can tease the problem out by creating a minimal example; currently there seems to be a lot going on in your program.

Comment: @Boann Okay, I've been looking into the problem and I've pin pointed it, it's a rounding error somewhere, when the Alpha is >0.5 it works, but when <0.5 it goes straight to 0. I worked this out by drawing a gradient from 0->1 and found that it cuts off exactly half way down. Can you see where the rounding error would be in the normal code?

Comment: @ShaunWild I can't see anything mathematically that could cause that. Are you sure you're exporting the image properly? Perhaps the program you use to make it is removing all pixels with less than half opacity as an "optimization". For example does it work any better if you use the image I made (https://i.imgur.com/EIP794Y.png)?

Comment: @Boann no i tried manually inputting pixels, look at my edited question.

Comment: @ShaunWild I have looked at that, but it doesn't demonstrate any problem. Look: `int colour = 0x79FF0000; float aA = (colour >> 24) & 0x000000FF; System.out.println(aA); // 121 (correct)`. Likewise, your `normal` method works fine when I use it. It's very hard to make sense of the problem when you can't provide any code reproduces it.

Comment: `int aA = (a >> 24) & 0xff;` if `a=0x79FF0000`, then this returns `254//incorrect`, if `a=0x80FF0000` it returns `128//correct`

Comment: @ShaunWild http://ideone.com/z5CR0i

Comment: @Boann What the heck? I have the exact same code it returns 254.. If i print that very same code into my main method it works fine, but in my normal method it returns a different value?

Comment: i just ran it again and it worked. I literally changed nothing. EDIET okay, if i render the transparency onto my bitmap then render it onto another it make half of it dissapear again.

Comment: @ShaunWild Are you getting muddled between `(a >> 24) & 0x000000FF` and `(colour >> 24) & 0x000000FF` ? I assumed the different variable name was just an unimportant typo when you edited it into the question.

Comment: That was "psuedo code" of the issue, my actual variable is a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your blit function:

```
if (col < 0 && (tp+xx) < pixels.length){
        pixels[tp + xx] = normal(col, pixels[tp + xx]);
}
```

this is not going to handle transparency because `col` can be greater than 0.

```
if ((tp+xx) < pixels.length){
    pixels[tp + xx] = normal(col, pixels[tp + xx]);
}
```

is all that is required..

Comment: Can i kindly ask a moderator to ban me and can i just say the biggest thank you to @Boann for wasting his time for me. Simple mistake, fixed.

Comment: Huh. Never mind, it happens :) I didn't see the error either. I foolishly glossed over that function because of the many variables. P.S. I guarantee if you swap that function out for a Graphics.drawImage call using the asBufferedImage() function I suggested on your other question, it will go at least twice as fast with half the hassle.

Comment: @Boann, I'll definitely give it a shot. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing), your formulas for adding two pixels are wrong.

**Edit(2)**:

- The `normal` operator is not commutative. There is a clear difference between background and foreground. You need to swap the arguments thus:

  normal(pixels[tp + xx],col);

instead of:

normal(col,pixels[tp + xx]);

- The first error is in alpha value extraction, you use:

  int aA = (a >> 24 & 0xff); //read by a compiler as (a >> (24 & 0xff))

use

```
int aA = (a >> 24) & 0xff;
```

instead.

- You should use:

`int A = (int) (aA+bA*(1-srcAlpha));
    int R = (int) (aR*srcAlpha+bR*dstAlpha*(1-srcAlpha));
    //...`

Why do you add `0.5`?

**Performance optimization**:

In order to optimize performance, you can circumvent using floating point operations, by shifting back the result:

```
int cA = 0xff-aA;
int A = aA+bA*cA/0xff;
int R = (aR*aA+bR*bA*cA)/0xff;
//...
```

Comment: 0.5 is for rounding to int.

Comment: I actually added 0.5f because it was mentioned in a previous answer that got deleted. I'll try these modifications now.

Comment: This formula performs no differently compared to Boann's.

Comment: @ShaunWild: Indeed, the error is in alpha value extraction: use `(a >> 24) & 0xff` instead of `(a >> 24 & 0xff)`...

Comment: @CommuSoft Was my first thought too. But `(a >> 24 & 0xff)`, although it looks dodgy and would be faster written as `(a >>> 24)`, is not wrong.

Comment: @Boann: But if one calculates the formulas through with `bA==0`, you clearly see, the original values (of the color behind) are used. Thus at least at the edges, this formulla should work correct.

Comment: @Boann: Well at the edges of the circle, the alpha channel is zero, if you calculate this through, the background color should be returned.

Comment: @ShaunWild: You probably swapped the two operator arguments. What if you call `pixels[tp + xx] = normal(pixels[tp + xx],col);`

Comment: I have changed it all as you specified and the result is still the same, I'll print the current code in my question.

Comment: @CommuSoft `a` is the circle, `b` is the background.

Comment: @ShaunWild: could you provide both image files please?

Comment: http://imgur.com/NZaW8kw , imgur is responsible for the gray background, the actual background is transparent.

Comment: @CommuSoft if I swap them around then nothing is drawn.

Comment: @ShaunWild: don't you have access to some kind of ftp server, so that one is sure the file is "untouched".

Comment: "Error (509) This account's public links are generating too much traffic and have been temporarily disabled!" :(

Comment: It will be available soon

Comment: okay it's not loading haha, if you open any image editing software and draw a white blob in the middle using a brush tool then you'll get the same image

Comment: Yeah, but in many cases this is because the alpha channel is not zero at the edge of the ellipse...